# Multiple W2s, Traditional IRA Deductions

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, ira

I changed jobs in the middle of 2019, which means I have multiple W2s. My job in the earlier part of the year did provide me with a 403b retirement plan, so there's a check in the "Ret plan" subsection of section 13. The second W2 does not have a check for "Ret plan".

The first W2 represents about $40k of income, while the second represents about $56k. I understand the combined income puts me way over the deduction limits for a traditional IRA, but since the second W2 doesn't have a retirement plan is my income only $40k for deduction purposes? I'm a single filer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The income limits for whether a contribution is deductible or not is based on your Modified Adjusted Gross Income (MAGI) for the whole year.